# Admin pages missing css

Tags: css, admin-css

suddently my admin page lost his css I think.. 
It looks like this:
[image]

I've read some topics with similar problems and I've already tried to:
- clearing browser cache and changing browsers
- reinstall wp core files.
- disabling plugins.
- editing the line in load-styles.php, to: error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
- adding in wp-config.php the lines: define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
define( ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’, true );

Google Chrome console shows these errors:[image]

But nothing is working.. what else could I try?

Comment: first of all have a look at the chrome console by right-click->inspect element somewhere in the page you will see the errors

Comment: @AndreaSomovigo post edited with the errors

Comment: Check your server's filesystem permissions

Comment: Talk with your hosting provides to check files being blocked.